# python virtualenv not working after setting path

Tags: python, django, powershell

So I installed Python 3.6 and set the environment path to it like :
`C:\Users\danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\`.

When I try to create a virtual environment (e.g. virtualenv Venv) it is not working. I get the error:

> `" The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."`

The path is set correctly. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: have you installed virtualenv?? try to install virtualenv once and then try

Comment: how did you set the path ?

Comment: Forgot to install it. It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it is working or not

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname
```